# Rails Friendly URLs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, permalinks, seo

I have a model called Project and I've defined the "to_param" method as this:

```
def to_param
  permalink
end
```

I am using this permalink plugin github.com/febuiles/make_permalink so when I call p.permalink it will generate id-name.

The problem is that when I TYPE /projects/1 in my web-browser the URL doesn't change to /projects/1-name. How can I achieve that?

Look that when I go to http://railscasts.com/episodes/63 the URL changes to /63-name

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like Ryan is using a conditional redirect to the proper episode_url. The Railscasts application source code is on GitHub, so you can [see how he does it](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts/blob/c9d6386feb15f9fea9129047d540a8de7b8063f4/app/controllers/episodes_controller.rb#L25-41).

Similarly as Drew suggests, this should work fine in your case.

```
redirect_to @project, :status => 301 if params[:id] != @project.to_param?
```

Comment: Thank you!! I can't give you reputation but THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4):

They are most likely using the friendly_id gem or something similar:

http://github.com/norman/friendly_id/

The important part is:

```
@post = Post.find(params[:id])
redirect_to @post, :status => 301 if @post.has_better_id?
```